# Custom post type with password not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created custom post type in Wordpress. I would like to protect the post with password, so I enabled it for one. If I go to the post page it displays first password form and below the whole post content. Password protection not working at all. Why?
On standard post type password protection works. I modified post template base on deafault single.php from theme. To custom post type I use CPT-UI plugin.

Comment: Is your template for custom post type using the function "post_password_required()" ?
More information here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection

Comment: No, I didn't use the function. Could you check how to apply it to my code? https://codeshare.io/arxqN7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Wrap the div with class "content-inner" and the content inside it in the div with in this if condition.

**Updated**

```
<?php if ( ! post_password_required() ) { ?>
<div class="content-inner">
    //... your content here
</div><!-- #.content-inner -->
<?php
    }else{
       echo get_the_password_form($post->ID);
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked, the content is hidden. However, the form to enter the password does not display.

Comment: Yes, now it works. After "else" should be "echo" also. Thank you!

Comment: This did the trick for me, too. I left the header and footer elements outside of the wrapped content, and styled the form (CSS) to make it look better. Thank you!